# PHP loop outputting duplicates

Tags: php, ranking

```
public function select(){
    $rows = [];
    $connection = $this->connect();
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT username FROM users");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $userlist = 0;
    foreach($rows as $username){
        $userlist .= $username['username'];
    }

    $get_rankings = [1,2,3,4];
    $get_image_path = "images/";
    $total = 0;

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($get_rankings); $x++){
        $total = $get_rankings[$x];
        $path .=  "<img src = '" . $get_image_path . $total . ".png'>\n" . $userlist . "<br/>";
        // echo "<span  class = 'align-down'>{$path}";
        // echo "<p class = 'user-name'> {$rows['0']}</p>";
        // echo "</span>";
    }

    echo $path;
}
```

I'm trying to output a simple ranking but using the number index as images to display them.

In the past i've tried to do something similar but couldn't figure out how to match player it with images on the side.

The output im getting is this:

[image]

It's outputting each entry 4 times(I get why, its in a loop) but I can't figure out the correct solution to write it outside of a loop or properly

The desired output is:

[image]

My DataBase reads as:

```
[id][username][password]
```

If there is an easier solution, i'm all ears.  I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: `$userlist .= $username['username'];` You're concatenating all of the users together in one string, and then outputting that string (will _all_ of the names smushed together) each time through the loop.

Comment: Initialize your $path variable before the _for_ loop : `$path = "";` in order to remove the _notice_ message.

Comment: What out put you are expecting ?

Comment: @RavinderReddy , Im expecting something like this: https://i.gyazo.com/b28180d98e45b61ef4c5501a32a3bb8c.png but instead it will show 1,2,3,4 based on my images

Comment: @PatrickQ when I remove the .= , I can't access rows, it just displays 1 result and its always the last result.  

.= allowed me to use the variable outside the foreach loop.  I dont know the solution

Comment: @JordanBrown Wait a second, how are you determining `rank` if there is no rank column in your `users` table?  Are you ORDERing or LIMITing the resultset in a way not posted in this question?  Is `rank` just an arbitrary value (assigned from the static array `$get_rankings`)?  Is this array just meant to limit how many rows you want to display on the screen?  I think there are a few refinements that I can share.  Please leave me a comment to explain all of these points and I should be able to post a professional grade answer tomorrow.

Comment: @mickmackusa There is no rank column but it's being determined based on the users level OR total experience. I can't remember.  It's live and working over here: http://socialven.x10host.com/projects/GunzSite/ .  It was so long ago, I don't really remember what I wrote.  I can dig it up if you want to see the code.

Comment: @JordanBrown if the rank is coming from another table then a mysql `JOIN` is in order.  If there is a five user maximum, then that should be in the query too.  To provide the most accurate answer, more details are necessary.   Barmar is not a sloppy poster, he should get first crack at answering the updated question.

Comment: @mickmackusa From the time I wrote this script, I learned a load more about programming in general.  I also now use the JOIN to connect certain tables when I need certain information.  The stuff I posted long ago like these are pretty obsolete in terms of what I know now.

Other than that, you seem so knowledgeable about everything.  I seriously hope we can keep in touch.  It'd be nice to have someone who I could hit up if I needed information/help.

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `$userlist`. Output the username from `$rows[$x]`.

```
$path = "";
$max = min(count($rows), count($get_rankings));
for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++){
    $total = $get_rankings[$x];
    $path .=  "<img src = '" . $get_image_path . $total . ".png'>\n" . $rows[$x]['username'] . "<br/>";
    // echo "<span  class = 'align-down'>{$path}";
    // echo "<p class = 'user-name'> {$rows['0']}</p>";
    // echo "</span>";
}
```

Comment: I think it should be $rows[$x]['username'] to display username